# django-taggit exception error: Table 'app_name.taggit_taggeditem' doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have installed django-taggit for a blog as part of my project using python 2.7 & django 1.4.6.

I have pip installed django-taggit and then used south migration to add the db settings.

When I attempt to add the blog entry through the admin page, I receive the following error:

```
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'app_name.taggit_taggeditem' doesn't exist")
```

I have checked the south migration logs - these seem ok.

I have added from taggit.managers import TaggableManager to my models.py page.

I have added 'taggit', to my installed_apps in my settings.

I have gone over my work - but cannot locate the issue.

Any suggestions?